# Calling self inside a block for an asynchronous REST request

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble calling `[self userLoggedIn]` when it is within the `withBlock` block. It gets called but it doesn't show the TITHomeViewController. If I move it below and outside the block then it works correctly. Obviously though, I want it to be called from within `withBlock` as that is the completion handler for an asynchronous REST request.

```
- (void)doAuth
{
    // Call the Facebook API /me method
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         // Populate global Facebook user info
         self.fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
         self.fbUserID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

         // Authenticate with the Titter API
         [self callAPI:@"auth" withBlock:^(NSDictionary *jsonData) {
             NSString *_id = [jsonData objectForKey:@"_id"];
             if (_id != nil) {
                 self.userID = _id;
                 [self userLoggedIn];
             }
         }];
     }];
}

- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Display the home view.
    self.window.rootViewController = [[TITHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TITHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
}

- (void)callAPI:(NSString *)path withBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *jsonData))block
{
    // Initialize the API callback URL using global root and given path
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", apiRoot, path]];

    // The Titter API requires an authorization header formatted as [userID]@[accessToken]
    NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", self.fbUserID, self.fbAccessToken];

    // Create the request and add our authorization header
    NSMutableURLRequest *restRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [restRequest addValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

    // Queue required for calling sendAsynchronousRequest
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // Make an asynchronous request to our API and if there is no errors, return formatted JSON data to the passed block.
    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:restRequest
     queue: queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error) {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil) {
             NSLog(@"Succeeded! Data as string: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);

             // Convert received JSON data into a NSDictonary object.
             NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

             // Call back the block passed in.
             block(result);
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }
         else if (error != nil) {
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Which `NSLog` gets outputted from the `completionHandler` in `callAPI:withBlock:`?

Comment: @Rich "Succeeded!" is returned and the block is called correctly. In  `TITHomeViewController` I am also outputting an `NSLog` for `viewDidLoad` and that's being outputted so the view is being loaded. It's just not showing on the app for some reason.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, set a background color: `self.view.background = [UIColor redColor];` and also put a `NSLog` in `viewDidAppear:`. Also in `userLoggedIn` add `NSLog(@"Main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO");`

Comment: @Rich Thanks, I've added those debug statements and here is the output. The weird thing is that if you wait about 5-10seconds after the viewDidAppear message the HomeViewController eventually did actually show. It had the red background correctly. But why did it take so long? Something to do with the main thread?

`2014-05-01 14:51:21.975 Titter[4630:4007] HomeViewController viewDidLoad`, `2014-05-01 14:51:21.977 Titter[4630:4007] userLoggedIn Main thread? NO`, `2014-05-01 14:51:24.861 Titter[4630:60b] HomeViewController viewDidAppear`

Comment: "userLoggedIn Main thread? NO" that is bad! You should be using UI operations on the main thread. Try putting the `NSLog(@"Main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO");` (with some better descriptive text!) in each of the completion blocks :)

Comment: @Rich Looks like it loses main thread in this block: `[self callAPI:@"auth" withBlock:^(NSDictionary *jsonData) {` Any tips to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment thread above got you about 90% of the way there! The UI runs on the main thread, and any updates to it should be made on the UI thread. You can fix this in your block code by calling `usedLoggedIn` on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self userLoggedIn];
});
```

It's also worth noting that you *might* run into problems using `self` inside the block: if `self` goes away, this block will fail. This might not be a problem in this use case. You don't mention what class this code is from: if it's from the view controller, it might be safe to assume that it's not going anywhere. But, if it's a helper object or something like that, it could disappear out from under you while the URL is being requested (or somewhere in that logic). It's common practice to create a weak reference to `self` for use inside a block, like so:

```
// Outside the block
MyViewController __weak *weakSelf = self;

// Inside the block
[weakSelf userLoggedIn];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation. I feel like I'm slowly getting a better understanding of threaded programming.

Comment: The main reason to avoid using `self` in a block is because it can lead to a circular reference. This isn't the case with `dispatch_async`; there's no reference from `self` to the block, and the `dispatch_async` copies the block so `self` ought to be returned automatically. The `weakSelf` pattern shouldn't be necessary here. However, it's worth noting that this will cause any deallocation of `self` to be deferred until after the block has been run if the `weakSelf` dance *isn't* used.